# android AccessibilityService suddenly stopped triggerring events - check my code please

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

I have an AccessibilityService which was working fine but for some reason during development it stopped working. I can't seem to find that reason. Please have a look at my code and tell why it isn't working.

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "event triggered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected() {
    AccessibilityServiceInfo config = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    config.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOWS_CHANGED;
    config.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;

    config.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS;

    setServiceInfo(config);
    super.onServiceConnected();
}
```

Here's the relevant part of Manifest:

```
 <service
        android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/myserviceconfig" />
    </service>
```

Here's myserviceconfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowsChanged"
android:notificationTimeout="100"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:settingsActivity="com.example.android.apis.accessibility.TestBackActivity"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

The code attempts to detect when the user has started a new Activity of a third party app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below is definitely problematic.

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected() {
    AccessibilityServiceInfo config = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    config.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOWS_CHANGED;
    config.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;

    config.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS;

    setServiceInfo(config);
    super.onServiceConnected();
}
```

The line: 
    AccessibilityServiceInfo config = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();

Is for sure innapropriate. By fetching a non initialized service config object, you have removed any of the configuration you did in your service config XML file. In fact, there is no reason to do any of your configuration programmatically, you should probably just remove this function, and change all of these settings in your service config.  EITHER of the following solutions would work.

> Fetch you services current configuration, instead of instantiating a
>   new one.

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected() {
    AccessibilityServiceInfo config = getServiceInfo();//This IS A REALLY IMPORTANT CHANGE!!! 
    //By instantiating a new "AccessibilityServiceInfo" you have overwritten all of your XML Config changes, as well as any default settings internal to Android! 
    //DON'T instantiate your own ServiceConfig objects!!!! Just don't. In fact, do everything in XML instead!

    config.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOWS_CHANGED;
    config.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;

    config.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS;

    setServiceInfo(config);
    super.onServiceConnected();
}
```

> Just make all of these changes in your service config xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowsChanged"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
    android:settingsActivity="com.example.android.apis.accessibility.TestBackActivity"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true" />
```

Notice that the flags you were adding in code are available in the service config file as well! Just use this, it's much easier. In this solution you should simply delete your `onServiceConnected` override function completely.

> Finally

Development of Android Accessibility Services is quite finicky! Android Studio does not always handle crashes well, particularly as it pertains to getting crash data into LogCat in an identifiable reliable manner and/or crashing vocally. Tracking down runtime exceptions can be a pain. Make sure when you experience sudden inconsistency like this, that you don't filter LogCat by application! Check the entire Log at Error level for stack traces and exceptions! ALSO, try uninstalling your service and running it again AND THEN inspecting the entire LogCat output. Turning your device on and off can help as well. YEP, it's a pain!

Between the solutions above, and these notes, you should be able to track down your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I got rid of the onServiceConnected() method. But I found that for some reason typeWindowsChanged was not being called. Someone suggested that I should use typeWindowStateChanged. This worked for me. Although it triggers far more often, I think this is even better for stability.

Comment: BUT there's a problem. Sometimes the app decides to stop listening to events and then I have to restart the device to listen again.

Comment: I would say that this either falls under my conclusion paragraph regarding the poor Accessibility Service dev support OR that you have some exceptions happening somewhere and your service is shutting down. You HAVE to have very stable service code, crashes are not always obvious!

Comment: If you goal is to catch all screen updates, I would recommend the following settings for eventTypes "typeWindowContentChanged|typeWindowsChanged|typeWindowStateChanged". You're going to get a lot of extras, you'll want to filter them out manually.

Comment: When the code throws an exception, I see the crash and the logcat, and then the app continues to report the events again. But sometimes it just goes silent and I have to restart the device to get the events to trigger again. One strange thing also happened, that another third party app started having problems with its accessibility service since today.

Comment: I have multiple accessibility services on the app store, none of them are having issues. I can't tell if you're trying to suggest that there's suddenly a new bug with accessibility services across android.  There is not. This question is too broad and discussion becoming too long. If you have more qeustions, you should ask them separately. I feel the value of continuing this discussion on this post for the broader StackOverflow community is minimal at best.

Comment: If you do have them, feel free to link them here! Will happily answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466460/android-accessibility-service-suddenly-stopped-triggering-events# pls help me...